# How to know which button was pressed on Android application download window

Tags: android

Is there a way to know programmatically which button the user pressed (Install or Cancel) on android application download/install window? I had some luck finding information how to know if aplication was installed but no success if cancel button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Ice Cream Sandwich, the package installer activity does not return a result. It always returns that the activity was canceled, even if the user did not cancel it.

In Ice Cream Sandwich, you can pass the `Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT` extra with your package installer intent to get a result from the package installer. See the docs for more details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE